# Orthogonal projection matrix onto a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, projection-matrices

Consider vector space $\Bbb R ^n$ and the subspace $\mathbf B \subset \Bbb R ^n $ spanned by the columns of matrix $\mathrm B$. Can it be shown that an orthogonal projection from $\Bbb R ^n$ onto $\mathbf B $ is given by the expression $\mathrm B(\mathrm B^T \mathrm B)^{-1} \mathrm B^{T} \mathrm v = proj_\mathbf B \mathrm v$ ; $\mathrm v \in \Bbb R ^n$ ?

Comment: What does your matrix do to a vector orthogonal to $B$? What does it do to a column of $B$? If the answers are "sends it to zero" and "leaves it fixed", then you're done.  But be careful to check the case where $B$ is not full-rank.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Where are you having difficulty? Please show your work so far.

Comment: I found the answer I needed here: (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963632/proving-a-given-formula-for-projection-matrix?rq=1) .  In particular, $\mathrm B(\mathrm B^T \mathrm B)^{-1} \mathrm B^{T} \mathrm B(\mathrm B^T \mathrm B)^{-1} \mathrm B^{T} = \mathrm B(\mathrm B^T \mathrm B)^{-1} \mathrm B^{T}$. ie the idempotency of $\mathrm B(\mathrm B^T \mathrm B)^{-1} \mathrm B^{T}$